# Can we say that $P(A\mid B) < P(A)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

and we know that $A \cap B \subset A$

So shouldn't $P(A \mid B) < P(A)$ ?

Comment: Take $A$ an event with $P(A)\lt 1$ and $B=A$, Then, $P(A|B)=P(A|A)=1\gt P(A)$

Comment: I don't know what $A\cap B<B$ means, but $P(A\cap B)\le P(B)$ always.

Comment: Since $A\cap B \subseteq B$ and so $\mathsf P(A\cap B)\leq \mathsf P(B)$, therefore $\mathsf P(A\mid B)\leq 1$, ... unsurprisingly.

Comment: thank you...why was my question downvoted though? this is the first time it happened and i want to ensure that it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake: $A \cap B < B$  should be $A \cap B \subseteq B$ , and we do have $P(A \cap B) \leq P(B)$.

Hence you can conclude that $P(A|B) \leq 1$.

We can't conclude for sure that $P(A|B) < P(A)$, in particular $A=B$ can be the event that a fair coin gives you tail.

Then $P(A|B)=1 \ge P(A)=\frac12.$

Comment: Why is knowing P(A|B) < 1 important here? I want to know how it is related to P(B)?

Comment: because that is the conclusion that you can reach from your working. You stated two quesiton. First, should $P(A \cap B) < P(B)$, not always, we can have $P(A \cap B) \le P(B)$. Second (from your title, that doesn't involve $P(B)$ at all, I have provided you with a counter example. Btw, $<$ , $\subseteq$, and $\le$ are not the same thing.

Comment: ohh thanks! Yeah I think my question was not framed properly...let me rewrite. thank you for pointing that out.